# Why the main thread doesn't get blocked when I use viewModelScope.launch without dispatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So in the ViewModel I have a function which does blocking and non blocking operations:

```
    fun doSomethingInViewModelScope(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            nonBlockingOne()
            count()
            nonBlockingTwo()
        }
    }
    fun nonBlockingOne(){
        Log.d("ViewModel","Should Be First")
    }

    fun nonBlockingTwo(){
        Log.d("ViewModel","Should be third")
    }

    suspend fun count(){
        var shouldCount = false
        var index = 0

        while (!shouldCount){
            delay(1000)
            Log.d("ViewModel","Counter: $index")
            index +=1

            shouldCount = index == 5
        }

        Log.d("ViewModel","Should be second")
    }
```

Till now, I thought that, if I run this, the order of the logs will be something like this:

```
Should Be First
Should be third
Counter: 0
Counter: 1
Counter: 2
.
.
.
Should be second
```

Or at least, the main thread will be blocked, so I won't be able to interact with the ui.

After I tried this out, I was surprised, because the execution happened in sequentially:

```
Should be First
Counter: 0
Counter: 1
Counter: 2
.
.
.
Should be second
Should be third
```

and the spinner in the ui wasn't frozen and I was able to interact with the UI.

So why is it happening? Theoretically without define the dispatcher, the default scope will be the main, if I do some heavy operation in the main thread, the ui should be frozen.

One more thing, what I tried out, if I set a new value to the LiveData in the following way: liveDdata.value = 10. I didn't get exception about this operation is can be done only in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the point of suspending functions. Unless you explicitly [`launch`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) another coroutine within your scope the code you write will execute sequentially.

You might also be under assumption that your `count()` function is blocking which it's not.

You use [`delay`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) which is suspending. While running in the context of `Dispatchers.Main` it will effectively do a `handler.postDelayed()` under the hood to continue execution later without occupying main looper in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you, in this case, if the suspend fun doesn't block the main thread, why I should use Dispatcers.IO when I want to do network call or IO operations? Maybe I'm a little bit confused right now, because I could run retrofit and room queries without define the dispatcher.

Comment: @Andreas1234 You use Dispatchers.Default to offload heavy CPU work and .IO to keep pool of blocked threads (eg. sockets). However well behaved suspending functions  (like those in Room and Retrofit) handle context switching internally and never block the thread they are called from so you should be free to call them even from main dispatcher.

Comment: Thank you again, one more question, you mentioned handler.postDelayed(), how can I imagine that? The lines under the suspend function call, in my example the nonBlockingTwo() method will be called, after the blocking one has finished?

Comment: @Andreas1234 I always recommend this [video about suspend functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQf-vtIC-Uc). While they look like code that is synchronous, in reality they are broken into pieces by the compiler. They are essentially state machines where suspending points are represented as labels while state and all variables are carried around in a `Continuation` object.